# How to pass file name into gpg commmand?

Tags: bash, filenames, gnupg

I am reading file name from a text file, and trying to pass them to `gpg` command to encrypt but it seems its not reading the variable.

content of Today.txt

```
nm.023000.input
nm.023001.input
nm.033000.input
```

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x


cat today.txt | while read line

do

echo $line ;
gpg --trust-model always   --output  $line.gpg --encrypt --recipient user1@gmail.com --yes  $line;


done
```

Output I get is:

```
+ input=today.txt
+ read line
+ cat today.txt
+ echo

+ gpg --trust-model always --output .gpg --encrypt --recipient user1@gmail.com --yes
+ read line
```

Out put Expected inside the bash script :-
gpg --trust-model always --output nm.023000.input.gpg --encrypt --recipient user1@gmail.com --yes nm.023000.input

the Goal is to create file

```
nm.023000.input.gpg
nm.023001.input.gpg
nm.033000.input.gpg
```

Comment: Well, what is in `today.txt`? A [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: Can’t reproduce. Is it `Today.txt` or `today.txt`? Are there empty lines in the file? Does the `while` loop only run once? Could you post the _actual_ code and the _actual_ input, i.e. a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of cat, you can read from input file and then read each line using while loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
input="ab.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
echo "${line}";
# gpg --trust-model always   --output  "${line}" --encrypt --recipient user1@gmail.com --yes  "${line}";
done < "${input}"
```

[image]

Comment: Needs more quotes to work reliably with all possible filenames. Make it `--output "$line.gpg"` and `"$line"`. Also, use `</dev/null` to stop gpg from consuming other content from the file.

Comment: Yes agree @CharlesDuffy let me udpate

Comment: (Similarly, `echo "$line"`, or better if we want to be able to see nonprintable characters visibly, `printf '%q\n' "$line"`)